# Per application disabling of WER "has stopped working" dialog

Tags: visual-c++, crash-reports, windows-error-reporting

I have a VC++ application with my own unhandled exception handler. I would like to prevent the WER "program has stopped working" message box from appearing when there is a crash. Using SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX does this, but it also seems to disable WER so that nothing is stored in the event logs. I would like WER to work normally storing an event, but just prevent the message box from appearing.

It sounds like the registry key DontShowUI=1 might do this but it seems to be global for the whole machine or user. So it would affect all other applications that the user might run.

Is there some way of doing this but only for my one application/exe ?

Comment: What you can do is [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513638(v=vs.85).aspx).  If it doesn't fit the bill then you'll have to do it yourself.  Which is largely the point of writing your own unhandled exception handler.  It is very unclear what kind of help you need to accomplish that, preventing WER from seeing the exception and adding a message to the event log are not difficult.

Comment: If you have an unhandled exception handler, why should Windows recognize your crash any longer? You're doing something wrong in your unhandled exception handler.